# CSP frame-ancestors self directive blocks page served from same origin

Tags: javascript, iframe, content-security-policy, same-origin-policy

I have a nodejs app which serves
`index.html` for "/" route
`test.html` for "/test" route

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/test.html"));
});
```

index.html has an iframe which embeds /test as below

```
   <iframe
        width="100%"
        height="500px"
        src="http://localhost:5500/test"
        sandbox
      ></iframe>
```

In server.js, I am applying CSP as below:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors self");
  next();
});
```

The content from `/test` route is blocked by Chrome saying
[image]

As per [MDN for frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors),
[image]

The URL scheme and port are same for both are same i.e. http://localhost:5500

Host:
[image]

Content being iframed can be access independently:
[image]

Why is `http://localhost:5500/test` not being considered as sameorigin when compared to `http://localhost:5500`?

Minimal reproducible example - https://github.com/phalgunv/csp-demo-same-origin

Comment: You need to allow the domain into your policy that you want accessing. Strict policies you add individual domains and their directories to prevent XSS.

Comment: I would try ("Content-Security-Policy", "connect-src 'self' https://*.example.com/*;")

Comment: As per MDN connect-src directive restricts the URLs which can be loaded using script interfaces. In my case, the content is being loaded by iframe.

Comment: Why do I need to add domain explicitly into CSP when it is on the same origin?

Comment: Apologies, you'd need to just Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors self localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try surrounding "self" in single quotes:

```js
res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'self'");
```

Comment: I noticed only now that MDN explicitly specifies it.